# Python : Web Scraping Specific Keywords

Tags: python, web, web-crawler, screen-scraping, scrape

My Question shouldn't be too hard to answer, The problem im having is im not sure how to scrape a website for specific keywords.. I'm quite new to Python.. So i know i need to add in some more details , Firstly what i dont want to do is use Beautiful Soup or any of those libs, im using lxml and requests, What i do want to do is ask the user for an input for a website and once its provided , Send a request to the provided URL, once the request is made i want it to grab all the html which i believe ive done using html.fromstring(site.content) so all thats been done the problem im having is i want it to find any link or text with the ending '.swf' and print it below that.. Anyone know any way of doing this?

```
def ScrapeSwf():
     flashSite = raw_input('Please Provide Web URL : ')
     print 'Sending Requests...'
     flashReq = requests.get(flashSite)
     print 'Scraping...'
     flashTree = html.fromstring(flashReq.content)
     print ' Now i want to search the html for the swf link in the html'
     print ' And Display them using print probablly with a while condition'
```

Something like that .. Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes my attempt:

```
import requests [1]
response = requests.get(flashSite) [2]
myPage = response.content [3]
for line in myPage.splitlines(): [4]
    if '.swf' in line: [5]
        start = line.find('http') [6]
        end = line.find('.swf') + 4 [7]
        print line[start:end] [8]
```

Explanation:

**1**: Import the request module. I couldn't really figure out a way to get what I needed out of lxml, so I just stuck with this.

**2**: Send a HTTP GET method to whatever site that has the Flash file

**3**: Save its contents to a variable

Yes, I realize you could condense lines 2 and 3, I just did it this way because I felt it makes a bit more sense to me.

**4**: Now iterating through each line in the code, going line by line.

**5**: Check to see if '.swf' is in that line

Lines 6 through 8 demonstrate the string slicing method that [@GazDavidson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146642/gaz-davidson) mentioned in his answer. The reason I add 4 in line **7** is because '.swf' is 4 characters long.

You should be able to (roughly) get the result that provides a link to the SWF file.

Comment: Yours Seems alot cleaner than mine, ill post mine below its gonna take me a minute cause im coding in a VM and using my normal browser outside of the vm

Comment: Wow didnt know Enter would send the comment anyways here we go 'def ScrapeFlashFiles():
 flashSite = raw_input('Please Provide a web URL : ')
 print ' Sending requests... '
 flashReq = requests.get(flashSite)
 print ' Scraping content '
 flashTree = html.fromstring(flashReq.content)
 print 'Searching for keyword \'.swf\' '
 for line in flashReq.content.split('\n'):
  if '.swf' in line:
   print line
 print 'Flash Scrape Complete..' '

Comment: Your Comment helped alot as well thank you for that too

Comment: Anytime! As a reference, try pasting your code in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/). That helps to work with your code easier :-)

Comment: I Didnt think of that haha ,  i was gonna try using the Collab edit site which i believe is great for working with others but would work with multiple computer programming lol , I May ask more questions in the future i still have alot to learn , the tool im working on needs to do one more thing which is scrape two sites section for what games they have on every page and write all names to a text file then remove the doubles as best as possible, i just need to try doing it myself first then if i still cant figure that out ill have a question up(:

Comment: alrighty then! Ask away if you need anything. Don't forget to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was sufficient

Comment: Yeah i remember people saying that in other peoples problems but i just didnt know how to do it but i see it has the Check mark right there Thank you !

Comment: Also is there an area i can view for all my asked questions? like a list of them?

Comment: Yep, [see this Gyazo](https://gyazo.com/0cb2cb6ac9f836b9e8afdcd7446aeae4)

Answer (score 1):

You're using `lxhtml` to build the HTML into an object model, so you probably want to use `flashTree.xpath` to search the DOM using XML Path Language. Find the path you want in the source DOM and then write an xpath that extracts it, your web browser's developer tools and [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp) can help you.

I personally wouldn't bother, I'd just extract the text I needed using a regular expression (`re.find(pattern, flashReq.content)`) because it's quicker. If I didn't know regex, wasn't comfortable with them, or I wanted raw speed then I'd use a crude string extraction like so:

```
start = flashReq.content.find(text_before_it) + len(text_before_it)
end = flashReq.content.find(text_after_it, start)
text_you_want = flashReq.content[start:end]
```

Comment: i used xpath for another function but it relies on classID's or class in the html , which wont make it very useful as i would just have to go and view the page source anyways, i just want it to view all the html , then search all of it and display everything it finds using multiple 'print' commands.. i dont understand your code on the bottom can you explain a little more? sorry im still a little new to python

Comment: The code finds text before something, then text after it, then extracts the stuff in between. you can `print text_you_want`

You could always do: 
`for line in '\n'.split(flashReq.content):
    if 'swf' in line:
        print line`

Comment: I'm About to test that right now it seems like it could work, but hopefully i can figure it out ill get back to you in the next 10min

Comment: Okay so i Attempted it and it doesnt print anything , so i decided why not print the sites data but litterally all that showed up was some CSS and the body of the site was maybe 2 lines long in the terminal but was 995 lines in the browser.. not sure why this is happening..

Comment: The `split` method is applied incorrectly, should be `flashReq.content.split('\n').` Alternatively, use the `splitlines()` method it's much cleaner. I'll explain further in my answer